Stripe Payment Intent implementation
My project stack setup is Frontend(ReactJS + NextJS) and backend(Java).
We want to work on adding stripe checkout for payment.
After checking the official documentation, we found out that we can handle and create payment Intent for example directly in NextJS.
i'm asking what is the best approach handling Payment intent in the backend (Java) vs Nextjs.
what is the difference ? advantages vs drawbacks ?
is it bad having payment Intent logic in NextJS ?
Thanks for helping!

You should put the PaymentIntent creation/Stripe code where you'd keep all of your other API endpoints/logic. You don't need to create a separate backend inside NextJS if you already have a Java server running your backend logic.
